# Get concatenate string of multiple value variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I've a list of div

```
<div data-attr="sel" data-num="1"></div>
<div data-attr="notSel" data-num="2"></div>
<div data-attr="sel" data-num="3"></div>
```

I'm tryng to get a string only div with the data-attr="sel" set.

```
function SI_MoveTasks() {
    var getSelected = document.querySelector('[data-attr~="sel"]');
    var selectedNums = getSelected.dataset.num;
    alert(selectedNums);
}
```

Now i get (1), how can i get the concatenate string (1,3)?
Thanks for support.

Comment: You have jquery tagged; are you planning to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/0d54ethw/

Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` since the latter only selects the first element as opposed to all of them.

Then use for loop as shown below

```
var getSelected = document.querySelectorAll('[data-attr~="sel"]');
var selectedNums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < getSelected.length; i++) {
    selectedNums.push(getSelected[i].dataset.num);
}

alert(selectedNums.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use document.querySelectorAll to get all matching elements. document.querySelector returns only the first matching element, or null if there is none.

```
function SI_MoveTasks() {
    var getSelected = document.querySelectorAll('[data-attr~="sel"]');
    console.log(getSelected);
    var selectedNums = '(';
    for(var i=0; i< getSelected.length; i++) {
        if (selectedNums !== '(') {
          selectedNums += ',';
        }
      selectedNums += getSelected[i].dataset.num;
    }
    selectedNums += ')';
    alert(selectedNums);
}
SI_MoveTasks();
```

Thats a working code, jsFiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/3kjye452/